# Parametrizing a single test in gtest

Tags: c++, googletest

I'm looking for a gtest analog of pytest's *@mark.parametrize*.

I have a fixture and several *TEST_F*-s that use it. I want to parametrize some of those tests, having different set of parameters for each test.

The requirement of having different parameters doesn't allow me to use *TEST_P*. I could create the separate fixture derived from the main one for every test, but it yields too many boilerplate code.

Are there any options, or *TEST_P* is the only parametrization utility provided by gtest?

Here is an example. It is quite artificial but should illustrate my needs.

```
 class DBConnectionFixture : public ::testing::Test {                                    
     // create and store connection to database here                                     
 };                                                                                      

 // @parametrize(count = [1, 10, 50, 100])                                               
 TEST_F(DBConnectionFixture, TestFetchManyRows)                                          
 {                                                                                       
     auto rows = fetchRows(count);                                                       
     for (auto row : rows) {                                                             
         validateRow(row);                                                               
     }                                                                                   
     // some more code independent of count                                              
 }                                                                                       

 // @parametrize(errorKind = ["lost_packages", "reordered_packages", "broken_packages"]  
 TEST_F(DBConnectionFixture, TestWithNetworkError)                                       
 {                                                                                       
     mockNetworkError(errorKind);                                                        
     writeSomething();                                                                   
     readSomethingAndCheckCorrectness();                                                 
 }
```

Comment: Could you please post some example? It's hard to see what exactly are you trying to achieve.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Sure, I'll add a small example in a few minutes.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen I added an example.

Comment: I'm afraid you can't avoid creating a class for each type of parameter, but is it really that bad for code? It's about 2-3 lines of code to create it and inherit from your fixture and `::testing::WithParamInterface<T>`, if you don't need any additional setup.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen And what if `DBConnectionFixture` is already parametrized? It is not possible to inherit from several `WithParamInterface`-s.

Comment: Hmm, I see where this is going. You can extract a common interface fixture (like `DBConnectionFixtureBase`), but hierarchy starts to grow. At this point one could ask if the class has too many responsibilities, since there are so many things to test. The only thing left I could propose are [type-parameterized tests](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/release-1.8.0/googletest/docs/AdvancedGuide.md#type-parameterized-tests), but I'm not sure if that solves your problem, it's a feature for testing templates classes.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen I see the point. There are indeed many somewhat unrelated parameters. I hoped for the magic pill but probably the whole thing should be rewritten a bit :) Thanks!